# How to make Translucent Window class in netbeans platform in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, platform

I m making app in netbeans platform in java. i created window class as extends TopComponent in my module.now i want it as Translucent window.so how can i do that?

Comment: more research could have been done, i googled the threads title and came up with the java docs:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Answer (score 1):

[Window translucency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) has been available since AWT. Follow the link to find a couple of examples.

In case if the link ever goes dead, the package in question is:

```
java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency
```